# How to send multiple diagRequest messages in Vector CAPL?

Tags: request, diagnostics, capl, canoe

I'm currently writing some CAPL code that is executed when clicking a button. It shall send multiple Diagnostic Requests. But CANoe is always telling me, that it can only send one request at a time. So I need to delay the requests. The `diagSetRequestInterval` function did not work. And since it is NOT a testcase, the `testWaitForDiagResponse` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the request has been handled (either by a response from the target or by a timeout).

Since you are **not** in a test node you have to give back the control to the system, i.e. your function which did `diagSendRequest` shall end and you wait for some events on the bus to occur before you continue (otherwise the simulation would stall).

Once the request has been handled `on diagRequest ...` is called. Inside this event procedure, you could send the next request and so on.

#### Example:

Instead of:

```
myFunction()
{
  diagRequest ECU.ProgrammingSession req1;
  diagRequest ECU.SecuritySeed req2:

  diagSendRequest(req1);
  diagSendRequest(req2);
}
```

You would do something like this:

```
myFunction()
{
  diagRequest ECU.ProgrammingSession req1;
  diagSendRequest(req1);
}

on diagResponse ECU.ProgrammingSession
{
  diagRequest ECU.SecuritySeed req2:
  diagSendRequest(req2);
}
```

Timeout handling is a different topic, and left as an exercise :-)

Answer (score 0):

You practically want to implement multiple TP connection simultaneously in CANoe. I presume you have only one **Diagnostic Description** in the Diagnostic/ISO TP configuration, which lets you to use only 1 TP connection at a time.

You can implement multiple diag layers in Diagnostic ISO/TP on the same Communication channel, as much as you want, but with different namings.

In simulation node, you will only have to declare the request you want with a different namespace, corresponding to one of the diag layer name you earlier created.

This way you can virtualize the multiple TP connection in UDS for the CANoe environment.

OR, you do not use diagnostic layer support by CANoe, and you construct the whole message with UDS payload on your data link layer (CAN, FR).
Depends what kind of Data link layer (CAN,FR) and how many comm channels with diag layer you have set.

In Flexray, for example ,you can send multiple diag requests in the same frcycle, if your frschedule provides multiple frslots in dynamic segment which the Diaglayer (or you) can use.